# Rails jquery atocomplete redirect to user

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) and have failed to achive redirect to selected user.

This is my form:

```
  <%= form_tag users_path, method: 'get', id: 'search-form' do %>
      <%= autocomplete_field_tag :search, 'Find your friends...', home_autocomplete_user_username_path, 'min-length' => 1, class:'search_field', onfocus: 'if($(this).val()=="Find your friends..."){$(this).val("");};', onblur: 'if($(this).val()==""){$(this).val("Find your friends...");};' %>
  <% end %>
```

It redirects to `users_path`, where it shows only selected user - but I want to redirect to his show page.

Actually I achived redirect to user adding:

```
    $('#search').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
      $('#search-form').submit();
      window.location.href = '/users/' + data.item.id;
    });
```

But I think it is not the best solution and there are better ones. Thank you in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will open the show page for you in a separate tab:

```
$('#search').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
    var url = "/users/" + data.item.id;
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    window.focus();
});
```

Let me know if any issue.

Comment: That's right, but I want to get this effect without use of js - I would preffer to use search form only (if it is possible).

Comment: Autocomplete provides you this js way of binding extra things you like to do....May I know any specific reason of not using the js way?